# How to convert multiple arrays into single multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

How can i convert multiple small arrays in to single multi-dimentional array.

i have main big array which contains small arrays like this .

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
    [length] => 1073709056
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_3.VOB
        )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
    [length] => 1073709056
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_1.VOB
        )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
    [length] => 1073709056
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_4.VOB
        )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
    [length] => 1073709056
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_2.VOB
        )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
    [length] => 295792640
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_5.VOB
        )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
    [length] => 39620608
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_01_1.VOB
        )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
    [length] => 274893
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cover & Label
            [1] => This Is 40 (2012) label.jpg
        )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
    [length] => 197602
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cover & Label
            [1] => This Is 40 (2012) cover.jpg
        )

    )

[8] => Array
    (
    [length] => 88064
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_0.BUP
        )

    )

[9] => Array
    (
    [length] => 88064
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => VIDEO TS
            [1] => VTS_02_0.IFO
        )

    )

[10] => Array
    (
    [length] => 64109
    [path] => Array
        (
            [0] => INFO TBS
            [1] => silver torrent logo.jpg
        )

    )
)
```

[length] is file size.

[path] is files path.

**if elements inside [path] is more than 1 then all the elements except the last are parent directories order while last element is the file-name.**
like this

```
 Array
        (
        [length] => 64109
        [path] => Array
            (
                [0] => directory
                [1] => sub-directory
                [2] => silver torrent logo.jpg
            )

        )
```

How can i convert above array in to following array.

```
Array
(
    [directory1] Array(
                        [file1.jpg] => 197602
                        [file2.jpg] => 274893
                        )

    [directory2]Array(
                        [file1.txt] => 41
                        [file2.txt] => 41
                        [sub-directory1]Array(
                                                [file1.txt] => 41
                                                [file2.txt] => 44
                                                [file3.txt] => 54
                                                )

                    )
    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

so far i have done like this

```
    foreach($old_files as $x)
    {

        if (isset($x['path'][1])){
    //$path=$x['path'][0];
    $path = @iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//ignore', $x['path'][0]);
    $path1 = @iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//ignore', $x['path'][1]);
    $files[$path][$path1] = $x['length']; 

        }else{
    $path = @iconv('utf-8', 'utf-8//ignore', $x['path'][0]);
    $files[$path] =  $x['length'];
        }
    }
```

above code works for the one level deep arrays but not for multi level deep arrays.

how can i solve this ?

Comment: What about file in a directory in a directory? Is this possible? And what about directory asd and dirsctory asd/asd/asd/asd/asd.jpg. How to difference them?

Comment: yes, there are directories in directory too. we can difference them using the count of arrays elements, the last element is filename .

Comment: Is it possible some directories have the same name? if so, we cannot know which is the parent directory.

Comment: yes, its possible, but each array consists the directory order, , please check the updated question.

Comment: oops, missed that part, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a variable to keep track of which inner array we are working on like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    $pointer = &$output;
    $path = $v['path'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($path)-1; $i++) {
        $dir = $path[$i];
        if (!array_key_exists($dir, $pointer)) {
            $pointer[$dir] = array();
        }

        $pointer = &$pointer[$dir];
    }

    $file = $path[count($path)-1];
    $pointer[$file] = $v['length'];
}
```

Comment: its perfect, thanks a lot.i used if condition to check the count inside the foreach loop, but yours is more appropriate.